# Limiting the current powering a circuit

Tags: batteries, current, low-power, current-limiting

I have an LED bar that draws about 1.17A when connected to a 5V 1A external USB battery. The voltage across the terminals measures 4.61V.

The LED bar draws about 1.7A when connected to a 5V 2A external USB battery. The voltage across the terminals in that case measures 5.1V.

In both case, I'm satisfied with the light it gives,but with the 5V 2A battery, it is quickly hot.

I only have 5V 2A batteries, and I'd like this LED bar to be powered with 5V 1A max, so it lights up AND does not heat up.

How can I do that ?
My electronic courses are a bit far by now.

Comment: "I have a LED bar that draws about 1A when connected to a 5V 1A external USB battery, and about 1.7A when connected to a 5V 2A external USB battery" - So you're overloading the 1A power bank, causing it's voltage to droop, otherwise the current would not be lower then the 1.7A the LED bar clearly draws @ 5V. Thus what you're asking is impossible, the only way to limit the current is to lower the voltage.

Comment: @Unimportant:Well... measured... when connected to any of 1A or 2A batteries, they both give 5.1V to the LED bar.

Comment: +1 to what unimportant said, and if you want the LEDs to run cooler, you will need to be satisfied with less brightness.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy:Let's assume I go this way. Solution would be a resistor is series, no ? (And this is the resistor who will heat up...)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy:About... unknown :) But they are marked with a DC4V making and supposed (and measured) to be 5630 LEDs. The bar is sold as 5V bar LED...

Comment: @Unimportant:My bad. When connected to tha 1A battery, it is powered with 4.61V 1,17A, and with the 2A battery, powered with 5.1V 1.7A

Comment: A resistor or resistors is possibly your solution. What are the specs for the LED bar? The resistor(s) may or may not heat up significantly, depending upon what the circuit looks like.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy: Circuit is... basic : a led bar, 2 red and black wires connected through an USB connector to an USB external battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the LED bar works well when its terminals are have 4.61V across them, then you should shoot for that as a target.

To get your 2A 5.1V battery bank to supply the LED bar with 4.61V you need to drop 5.1-4.61= 0.49V.

If the current through the LED bar is 1.17A when the voltage is 4.61V, you need a 0.49V/1.17A = 0.419\$\Omega\$ resistance.

The power such a resistance will use is 0.49 x 1.17 = 573mW. I would go with a 1 watt resistor, or multiple resistors with lower power ratings in parallel, or series (adjusting the resistance values as appropriate). Yes, a resistor dissipating 573mW will get warm to the touch, but if properly rated, and exposed to air, it should not be in danger of failure, nor of starting a fire.

There are sub-Ohm resistors available.

Comment: multiple lower resistors... in parralel ? Are you sure ? Not in series ?

Comment: @oliver lower _powered_ resistors in parallel. If you use parallel resistors, you must adjust the resistance value. If you want to use two resistors in parallel, they should each be 2 times the resistance (but can be half the power rating). If you want 3 resistors in parallel, they should each be 3 times the resistance, etc. It is also possible to use resistors in series. For 2 resistors in series, use 1/2 the resistance in each, etc.

Comment: Ok :) The way you wrote it mislead me :) ("adjusting the resistance as appropriate") That's clear. I suggest you update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I edited the answer. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes :) As an addition, if I want to go more down on the voltage than 4.61V, what formula should I use to calculate the right resistance to use ? Because then I won't have the current for this targeted voltage. And you use into the formula values that I had the chance to be able to measure having 2 batteries and find the voltage and current for both usages. But if I didn't have them...

Comment: Unfortunately, the voltage-current characteristics of diodes in general, and LEDs in particular, are not very linear. (In fact, they are an exponential term minus a constant). Furthermore, they change with temperature. A larger resistor will definitely lower the current somewhat, and the brightness along with it. But it is not an exact science unless you know the junction temperature and the reverse leakage current. Also, don't forget that your battery pack will lose voltage as it discharges, which will throw calculations off. Experiment will give you the _actual_ answers.

Comment: My guesstimate, is that if you want 1A instead of 1.17, try a 0.47\$\Omega\$ resistor. I bet it will be fairly close. 0.47\$\Omega\$ is a standard size.